# Check Box issue when Updating multiple values in Php

Tags: php

i have written a very simple script for updating multiple values in different columns.
My issue is that when i try to update values in columns it work fine, but in case of check box the values are inserting incorrectly.

for ex . if i have 7 rows to update and in selection option i select 1 , 2 , 3 check box and i don't select 4 5 and again select 6 7 then on updating it take select for 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 and leaving 6 7 unselected

i am pasting my codes here

form

```
     <?php include("db.php");

          $id = $_GET['id'];
   $tDate2=$_GET['tDate2'];
 ?> <form method="POST" style="width:50%" action="updatemonthly.php"  >
  <table id="rounded-corner">


    <?php
    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("monthly_pmc_admin") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from project_details where id ='$id' ;");
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
     $pno=$row['Project_No'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from capex_phasing_data where Project_Number ='$pno' order by id ;");
     ?>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="6" scope="col" class="rounded-company">Edit/ Delete Capex Graph Values</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1"> <?php echo $tProjNo ?></th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7" class="rounded-foot-left" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="DELETE" id='myButton1' />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE" id='myButton1' />
         <?php 
         echo 
          '<a href="../capex.php?id=' . $id . '&tDate2='.$tDate2.'"> Add New Capex Value</a>';
          ?></td>
        <td class="rounded-foot-right"></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="rounded-foot-left" align="center"> <?php 
            echo('<A hREF="http://10.26.162.84/graph1/default.aspx?id='.$pno .'&tDate2='. $tDate2. '" target="_blank"> View Graph </A>');?></td>
            <td class="rounded-foot-right"></td>
          </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th align='center'> Select to <br/>
        Delete Record </th>
      <th >Month</th>
      <th>Planned Phasing </th>
      <th>Actual Phasing </th>
       <th>Select To Display Value in Graph</th>

    </tr>
    <?
    for($i=1;$i<=mysql_num_rows($result);$i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td align='left' ><input  type="checkbox" name="chk[]"  value="<?=$row['id']?>" align='center' />
      </td>
      <td align='left'><input type="text" name="month[]" size="10" id="jj" value="<?php echo $row['Month'];?>"  />
      </td>
      <td align='center' ><input name="planman1[]"  size="50" type="text" id="rr" value="<?php echo $row['Planned_Phasing'];?>"  />
      </td>
      <td align='center' ><input name="planman2[]" type="text" size="8" id="r1r" value="<?php echo $row['Actual_Phasing'];?>"  />
      </td>

      <td align='center' ><input name="planman5[]" type="checkbox" id="r4r"  <? if($row['Select_project']==1) {echo 'checked';} ?>  />
      </td>

        <input  type="hidden" name="rowid[]"  value="<?=$row['id']?>" align='center' />
        <input type="hidden" name="ProjNo" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="tDate2" value="<?php echo $tDate2; ?>">
        <!--<input type="hidden" name="ProjNo" value="<?php echo $tProjNo; ?>">-->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     }
     ?>
```

update query

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('dbclass/database.php');
$myClass=new database();
//echo $_POST['name'];
  $array=$_POST['rowid'];
  $month=$_POST['month'];
  $planman1=$_POST['planman1'];
  $planman2=$_POST['planman2'];
  $planman3=$_POST['planman3'];
  $planman4=$_POST['planman4'];
  $planman5=$_POST['planman5'];
  $actuanman=$_POST['actuanman'];
  $length=count($_POST['rowid']);
  $chk=$_POST['chk'];
  $projno=$_POST['ProjNo'];
  $tDate2=$_POST['tDate2'];

  if($_POST['submit']=='UPDATE'){


for($a=0;$a<$length;$a++){
    $rid=$array[$a];
   $array[$a];
   $month[$a];
   $planman1[$a];
   $planman2[$a];
   $planman3[$a];
   $planman4[$a];
   $planman5[$a];
   $ac= $actuanman[$a];

 if($ac=='on'){$ch=1;} else {$ch=0;}


 if($planman5[$a]=='on'){$planman5[$a]='1';} else {$planman5[$a]='0';}

 $sql="UPDATE  capex_phasing_data set   Month='".$month[$a]."',   Planned_Phasing='".$planman1[$a]."' , Actual_Phasing='".$planman2[$a]."',    Select_project='".$planman5[$a]."' where id='".$rid."'";

mysql_query($sql) or die(); 

header("location:#");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after understanding i have found the solution for my own problem thank you lex and sujit for your precious  time and help

i have change in my form for the chck box as

```
<td align='center' ><input name="planman2[]" type="text" size="8" id="r1r" value="<?php echo $row['Actual_Phasing'];?>"  />
  </td>

  <td align='center' ><input name="**planman5<?=$i?>**" type="checkbox" id="r4r"  <? if($row['Select_project']==1) {echo 'checked';} ?>  />
  </td>
```

and in the update script

```
for($a=0;$a<$length;$a++){
$rid=$array[$a];
$array[$a];
$month[$a];
$planman1[$a];
$planman2[$a];
$planman3[$a];
$planman4[$a];
**$p=$a+1;
$p5= $_POST['planman5'.$p];
if($p5=='on'){$ch1=1;} else {$ch1=0;}**
```

now its working perfectly fine...

thank you for your help and the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you submit a form that has multiple select boxes, only the name of the checked ones will be in the `$_POST` array. So to know whether or not a checkbox was on you have to check for the occurence of its name in `$_POST`.

Comment: LEX thank you so much for your reply.... i have no idea how to do it. is it possible if you can make changes in my code it will be really very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same name followed by '[]' to all checkboxes belonging to one property.

e.g. if you are putting hobbies checkboxes as music, reading and surfing then all should have same name, something like hobbies[] and values as music, reading or surfing.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='hobbies[]' value='Music'>Music</input>
<input type='checkbox' name='hobbies[]' value='Reading'>Reading</input>
<input type='checkbox' name='hobbies[]' value='Surfing'>Surfing</input>
```

So if you check on music and surfing, you will get the respective **values of checked checkboxes in $_POST['hobbies']**

```
$_POST['hobbies'] as array('Music','Surfing')
```

So you can manage database values accordingly.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply... Actually there is one check box only it is having multiple rows. so i m trying to update one chchk box for multiple rows... can you please fix my code above ..

Comment: @yasar : before submitting form, check page source if you are getting values of checkboxes correctly on form.

Comment: yes before updating the values are displaying correctly... i am inserting values through different form , if in case i dont select the value for any row at insert query then it is displaying correctly...

Comment: @yasar : after $chk=$_POST['chk']; this line, where have you used $chk to update the record?

Comment: actually $chk i am using for delete query for deleting the row ....if($_POST['submit']=='DELETE'){
 
for($a=0;$a<count($chk);$a++){
 $array[$a];
 $month[$a];
 $planman1[$a];
  $planman2[$a];
   $planman3[$a];
    $planman4[$a];
  $planman5[$a];
 $actuanman[$a];
  $sql="delete from capex_phasing_data  where id='".$chk[$a]."'";
      
mysql_query($sql) or die(); 

header("location:#");
}
}

?>

Comment: i m really not very good with php programming ... if you can suggest me some other way for updating multiple rows for same colum ill be glad to change my codes...

Comment: you havent given "value" attribute for that field. give it and then check what comes in $_POST['planman5']

Comment: if i am trying to give the value then no values is displaying all becoming unchecked.....

Comment: its not possible. are you giving different values?

Comment: <input name="planman5[]" type="checkbox" id="r4r"  <? if($row['Select_project']==1) {echo 'checked';} ?>  /> if instead of this i try to use <input name="planman5[]" type="checkbox" id="r4r" value=" <? if($row['Select_project']==1) {echo 'checked';} ?> " /> ... its not working, actually i have to create a graph using these values and i have to take the values which is got selected so i have three colums with many rows so i have to select some of the rows while ignoring others for field planman5 its value is either 0 or 1 so its like multiple row chckbox for single colum

Comment: u r mixing logic of update and add here, first try with simple values, like use any  counter like $i=0 outside loop; use value=$i; and use $i++ just before closing loop. Till this tesing, comment the line that updates value in database.